# How to set colors in SweepGradient with correct angle?

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I want draw arc-indicator with gradient. For first trying I use green and red color.

Now my arc-gradient looks like:
[image]

But how to start RED color from top of my arc-gradient (270 degress between 90)?

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue .With the help of this code i solved my problem.Hope this code will 
help someone.

```
    //Make the gradient start from 270 degrees
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.setRotate(270,baseArcRect.centerX(), baseArcRect.centerY());
    sweepGradient.setLocalMatrix(matrix);


}
```